# List Categories (wp_terms) and count posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization

I have a problem (of course) and I'll go straight to the point:
I need to list all the custom categories and count the posts for each category
eg.

- Category 1 (xx posts)
- Category 2 (yy posts)
- etc..

I tried a couple of queries but with no luck.
All these categories are stored in the wp_terms table, how do I list them since I've seen that there isn't, apparently, any elations between wp_terms and the posts?
Worthless to say that i've tried wp_list_categories but it shows just "Uncategorized" since the website I'm using, uses custom post rather than "default" categores.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Erm... Every single term/post_tag/category object has a `count` built right into it. Have you ever tried doing a `var_dump()` of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling a little bit, I found a solution writing this:

```
<?php


$cat_args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'show_count' => '1', 'hierarchical' => '0','taxonomy' => 'here goes the taxonomy');?>
<ul>
<?php
        $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
        wp_list_categories(apply_filters('', $cat_args));
?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (I have tested it in a custom template file).

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("name_of_your_custom_taxonomy");

foreach($terms as $term)
{

echo $term->slug; // you can display term name, description ..... Look at codex to see the parameters


$items = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'name_of_your_custom_post_type)',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'taxonomy'    => 'name_of_your_custom_taxonomy',
    'term'        => $term->slug
    ) );


$count =  count( $items );
echo $count;
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks for this, it gives me an output (finally) but the results is the same no matter if I change the taxonomy, eg. if i change it from hotels to restaurants, the result is still "49".Also, i need that to list all categories/custom_taxonomies not only one